# TYPO3 v7.6.0 (create custom extentions)

Tags: plugins, controller, typo3, typo3-7.x

To create an extension using the Extension Builder. Then I add to the page. The result is an error. The logs the following text:
`Call to a member function findAll () on a non-object in .... DbtestController.php on line 43`.
I would like to know what is the reason? and how to fix it.
Is there a manual, to build extentions in typo3 v7.6.0?
The fact that up to this point I have worked with typo3 v4.6.

Comment: Please post the code around line ``43``. We cannot help you without knowing what you did.

Comment: line 43: `$dbtests = $this->dbtestRepository->findAll();`

Comment: are you injecting the repository ?

Comment: You're right. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an "ExtensionBuilder 7.6.0" manual at https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/extension_builder/ .